# How do you pass parameters to an HttpHandler using Kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, kendo-ui

I am very familiar with jQuery AJAX and use it all the time.  Kendo UI is built on top of jQuery and its' use of AJAX.  Interfacing with & passing parameters to an HttpHandler is easy using jQuery, you simply do the following:

**USING JQUERY AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
    complete: self.onComplete,
    data: { SiteId: 777 },  // <--- this gets appended to the post
    dataType: 'json',
    error: self.onError,
    success: self.onSuccess,
    url: self.url
});
```

**MY ISSUE:**
I am trying to find the KendoUI equivolent-call for `data` (above).

- While the grid DOES populate with data passed back to me from the HttpHandler
- The parameters are not being fed to the HttpHandler (see below)

**THE KENDO CODE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport:
                    {
                        read: {
                            url: "Handlers/Attempt1Synch.ashx",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { SiteId: 777 }
                        }
//                        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
//                            return JSON.stringify(data);
//                        }
                    },
                schema: { data: "People" }
            });

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                height: 360,
                width: 500,
                dataSource: dataSource,
                groupable: true,
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns:
                [{
                    field: "Id",
                    width: 0
                },
                 {
                     field: "FirstName",
                     width: 90,
                     title: "First Name"
                 },
                {
                    field: "LastName",
                    width: 90,
                    title: "Last Name"
                },
                {
                    width: 100,
                    field: "City"
                },
                {
                    field: "Title"
                },
                {
                    field: "BirthDate",
                    title: "Birth Date",
                    template: '#= kendo.toString(BirthDate,"dd MMMM yyyy") #'
                },
                {
                    width: 50,
                    field: "Age"
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="grid">
    </div>
```

**MY HTTP HANDLER LOOKS LIKE:**

```
public class Attempt1Synch : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var siteId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["SiteId"]);

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var response = mock(siteId);

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
        context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(response));
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come to find out that this was a known issue in their previous build.  [**The newest release fixes this**](http://www.kendoui.com/web/whats-new/release-notes/v1-2011-sp1-version-2011-3-1407.aspx). As such, you must FIRST download the latest version of `KendoUI` as shown below:

**V1 2011 SP1 (version 2011.3.1407) - February 2012**
 - see 'OData does not submit user defined parameters'

However, there is **also** an issue with the code above.  The code should **omit** the `POST` command altogether.

**THE NEW DATA SOURCE SHOULD LOOK LIKE:**
Only the `DataSource` object is incorrect. The new one should look like this -

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({                 
    transport:                     
    {                         
        read: 
        {
            url: "Handlers/Attempt1Synch.ashx",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { SiteId: 777 }
        },
        schema: { data: "People" }             
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the consise answer. Do you reccomend any blogs or tutorials on Kendo UI. I find Telerik's documentation and examples lacking.

Comment: No, I'm sorry I have had to get through this using 'trial-and-error'.  And yes, Telerik's documentation site does suck.